# Why is it possible to calculate with a calculator with new Function?

Tags: javascript

I referred to an article to make a calculator with js, but I don't understand why it can be calculated with new Function.
I looked it up in the official reference, but it's confusing.

```js
 var result = document.getElementById("result");
function edit(elem) {
  result.value = result.value + elem.value;
}
function calc() {
  result.value = new Function("return " + result.value)();
}
```

Also, in the reference, it looks like this:

```
const sum = new Function('a', 'b', 'return a + b');

console.log(sum(2, 6));
// expected output: 8
```

If you try to do something similar in my code, it should look like this:

```
 result.value = new Function("return  + result.value");
```

But this causes an error. Why?

Comment: *"But this causes an error. Why?"* It's probably told in the error message

Comment: `new Function("return + result.value")` - what are you hoping to accomplish with this edit?

Comment: I want to output the calculated value

Comment: Didn't the original code, `new Function("return " + result.value)()`, do that?

Comment: The original code was new Function ("return" + result.value) (). But, I thought it was different from the reference and asked.

Comment: Can you please add your HTML

Comment: I accidentally erased it.I Added html.

Comment: It is hard to understand what is your issue

Comment: Usually the Function constructor is used to create a function, with the last argument being the body and the preceding ones the names of the arguments to be used in that body.   It's only rarely useful, but then might be invaluable.  However, with no arguments, and with an immediate invocation of the function created, this is simply a disguised version of `eval`, and you might equally use `result.value = eval(result.value)`.  But as 3limin4t0r's answer points out, this is usually frowned upon.  Hence the silly Function constructor call.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming `result.value` is set to `"1+2"` then:

```
result.value = new Function("return " + result.value)();
result.value = new Function("return 1+2")(); //=> 3
```

Will create a function from a string and immediate invoke it.

Which is essentially the same as (there are some scoping differences):

```
result.value = eval(result.value);
result.value = eval("1+2"); //=> 3
```

However [`eval()` is evil](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/eval#never_use_eval!) (as is function creation from string) and should probably be avoided when it contains user input.